# When is a smooth homeomorphism a diffeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I would like to know when a smooth homeomorphism is actually a diffeomorphism. I know that if $f$ is a homeomorphism and an immersion (i.e. an embbeding), then $f$ is a diffeomorphism. However, I do not want to use the notions of immersion, submersion,...

I read somewhere that in low dimensions this actually happens. Is it true?

Comment: If you don't want to take a derivative, you can never actually know this. In low dimensions homeomorphic manifolds are diffeomorphic, but that doesn't mean that a smooth homeomorphism is a diffeomorphism. After all, $x \mapsto x^3$ is a smooth homeomorphism of $\Bbb R$ that's not a diffeomorphism.

Comment: oh ok! sure. that's a nice example to clear things up. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

From the comments: on $\mathbb R$, $x \mapsto x^3$ is a homeomorphism that is not a diffeomorphism (for the standard smooth structure). So without additional conditions, a smooth homeomorphism need not be a diffeomorphism.